# C# global variables unchangeable outside of locality?

Tags: c#

Variables declared and initialized in Main, are not able to be changed through methods belonging to
other classes. This is extremely unintuitive and there must be a way around this.

Anyone know why, and how to solve? Or am I not understanding something fundamental about inheritance.

[image: Screenshot of code and result]

```
TestClass stuff = new TestClass();

int test = 1;

Console.WriteLine("This is an integer: {0}\nAnd this is an amount it's added with: 2", test);

stuff.ChangeVariable(test);

Console.WriteLine("\nand it's {0} here! Why doesn't the change stick!?", test);

class TestClass
{
    public void ChangeVariable(int item)
    {
        item += 2;your text
        Console.WriteLine("\nFor some reason, 'item' here is {0},", item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not inheritance. Nested class definition dont really have anything to do with their parent class, its just syntax sugar that can be useful for scoping.

Comment: @pigeonhands Why aren't the changes done to 'test' persistent, I understand that variables declared within a method don't leave it, but the change, as well as the result are both contained to Main

Comment: You can pass it as ref

Comment: @Selvin What's "ref"?

Comment: Because the `int` is passed by value not by reference. The `item` parameter is a local variable and changes do not reflect on `test`

Comment: "something fundamental"

Comment: @Selvin I'm not very good at programming, and I'm not very familiar with some of the languages limitations, to me it seems unintuitive, but I don't know if I'm being stupid, that's what I mean by "something fundamental".

Comment: there are no global variables in c#

Comment: I suggest looking up "pass by reference" and "pass by value" , perhaps [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters) is a start

Comment: @SleepParalysisDemon One of the hardest things about programing is the simplest things require some amount of lower level knowledge to propperly understand. When you pass a value into a function, that value is copied In most cases (`ref` being an exception). The confusing part can be that the value of a Class instance in c# is a pointer, so if you did the same thing using a class instance that had a int field, it would work. However none of this specific to `OOP`, and has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: @SleepParalysisDemon for future regerence, tje .net framework and c# language are very well documented. C# ref in Google, tada; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref I would advise you to read everything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not understanding something fundamental.

Your code doesn't use inheritance. Your code has two classes but they don't inherit. You are using an implicit `Main` method that belongs to a class and you are defining a class named TestClass. These two classes have no relation to each other.

There are no global variables in C#. `int test` is a local variable in the implicit `Main` method.

`int` is a value type, not a reference type. When you pass `test` to the `ChangeVariable()` method, the value of `test` is passed but not a reference to the `test` variable. The changes made to `item` are limited to the `ChangeVariable()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the `ref` keyword, it won't change the variable in the other class.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

So if you want it to change the variable, your code should look like this:

```cs
using System;

TestClass stuff = new TestClass();

int test = 1;

Console.WriteLine("This is an integer: {0}\nAnd this is an amount it's added with: 2", test);

stuff.ChangeVariable(ref test);

Console.WriteLine("\nand it's {0} here! Why doesn't the change stick!?", test);

class TestClass
{
    public void ChangeVariable(ref int item)
    {
        item += 2;
        Console.WriteLine("\nFor some reason, 'item' here is {0},", item);
    }
}
```